# How to edit a pdf file, replacing its data?

Tags: python, pdf, edit, pypdf

I am trying to rotate pages in a pdf file, and then replace the old pages with the rotated ones in the SAME pdf file.

I have written the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
from pyPdf import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

my_path = "/home/USER/Desktop/files/"

input_file_name = os.path.join(my_path, "myfile.pdf")
input_file = PdfFileReader(file(input_file_name, "rb"))
input_file.decrypt("MyPassword")
output_PDF = PdfFileWriter()

for num_page in range(0, input_file.getNumPages()):
    page = input_file.getPage(num_page)
    page.rotateClockwise(270)
    output_PDF.addPage(page)

#Trying to replace old data with new data in the original file, not
#create a new file and add the new data!
output_file_name = os.path.join(my_path, "myfile.pdf")
output_file = file(output_file_name, "wb")
output_PDF.write(output_file)
output_file.close()
```

The above code gives me an error! I 've even tried using:

```
input_file = PdfFileReader(file(input_file_name, "r+b"))
```

but it didn't work either...

Changing the line:

```
output_file_name = os.path.join(my_path, "myfile.pdf")
```

with:

```
output_file_name = os.path.join(my_path, "myfile2.pdf")
```

fixes everything, but it's not what I want...

Any help?

**ERROR CODE:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "12-5.py", line 22, in
>   
>       output_PDF.write(output_file)   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyPdf/pdf.py", line 264, in write
>       self._sweepIndirectReferences(externalReferenceMap, self._root)   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyPdf/pdf.py", line 339, in
>   _sweepIndirectReferences
>       self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, realdata)   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyPdf/pdf.py", line 315, in
>   _sweepIndirectReferences
>       value = self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, value)   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyPdf/pdf.py", line 339, in
>   _sweepIndirectReferences
>       self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, realdata)   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyPdf/pdf.py", line 315, in
>   _sweepIndirectReferences
>       value = self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, value)   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyPdf/pdf.py", line 324, in
>   _sweepIndirectReferences
>       value = self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, data[i])   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyPdf/pdf.py", line 339, in
>   _sweepIndirectReferences
>       self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, realdata)   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyPdf/pdf.py", line 315, in
>   _sweepIndirectReferences
>       value = self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, value)   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyPdf/pdf.py", line 324, in
>   _sweepIndirectReferences
>       value = self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, data[i])   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyPdf/pdf.py", line 345, in
>   _sweepIndirectReferences
>       newobj = data.pdf.getObject(data)   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyPdf/pdf.py", line 649, in getObject
>       retval = readObject(self.stream, self)   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyPdf/generic.py", line 67, in
>   readObject
>       return DictionaryObject.readFromStream(stream, pdf)   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyPdf/generic.py", line 564, in
>   readFromStream
>       raise utils.PdfReadError, "Unable to find 'endstream' marker after stream." pyPdf.utils.PdfReadError: Unable to find 'endstream' marker
>   after stream.

Comment: what do you mean by "It didnt work" and "gives an error"

Comment: edited with the error code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue, I suspect, is that PyPDF is reading from the file as it's being written to.

The correct fix — as you've noticed — is to write to a separate file, then replace the original file with the new file. Something like this:

```
output_file_name = os.path.join(my_path, "myfile-temporary.pdf")
output_file = file(output_file_name, "wb")
output_PDF.write(output_file)
output_file.close()
os.rename(output_file_name, input_file_name)
```

I've written a bit of code which simplifies this: https://github.com/shazow/unstdlib.py/blob/master/unstdlib/standard/contextlib_.py#L14

```
from unstdlib.standard.contextlib_ import open_atomic

with open_atomic(input_file_name, "wb") as output_file:
    output_PDF.write(output_file)
```

This will automatically create a temporary file, write to it, then replace the original file.

**edit**: I had initially mis-read the question. Below is my incorrect but potentially helpful to other people answer.

Your code is fine, and should work without issue on "most" PDFs.

The issue you're seeing is an incompatibility between PyPDF and the specific PDF you're trying to use. This may be a bug in PyPDF or it may be that the PDF isn't totally valid.

Two things you can try:

1. See if PyPDF2 can read the file. Install PyPDF2 with `pip install PyPDF2`, replace `import pyPdf …` with `import PyPDF2 …`, then re-run your script.
2. Use another program to re-encode your PDF and see if that works. For example, using something like `convert bad.pdf bad.ps; convert bad.ps maybe-good.pdf` *might* fix things.

Comment: 1. Tried it! Many lines of error code. Starts with: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "12-5.py", line 22, in <module>
    output_PDF.write(output_file)

2. No idea how to do this!

Comment: My apologies — I had mis-read the question. See my updated answer.

Comment: ok, the os.rename thing works!
However, I think that the proper answer is that what I was trying to do can't be done that way, since  PyPDF is reading from the file as it's being written to! :)
But if someone needs to do it WITHOUT creating and saving a new pdf file in his hard drive, then sure os.rename is the way to do it!
And since this tottally does what I NEEDED even though not the way I thought of, I 'll choose this as a correct answer! :)

Comment: Ah yes — the reason I suggested this method is that it's the standard, safest method that almost all software uses (ex, if you're overwriting the file but your program crashes half way through you'll lose both the original and the new file, but with this method the original file will be safe). If you *really* want to unsafely overwrite the old file you'd read the entire original file into memory then open that with PyPDF: `PdfFileReader(StringIO(open(input_file_name).read()))`.