# Python Error: Unable to find 'endstream' marker after stream at byte

Tags: python, pdf, python-requests, pypdf

I am trying to run this Python code to open an existing pf -> Add bookmarks -> write to the existing pdf. However it is throwing the below error and I have never seen this one before?

> in readFromStream raise utils.PdfReadError("Unable to find 'endstream' marker after stream at byte %s." % utils.hexStr(stream.tell())) PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError: Unable to find 'endstream' marker after stream at byte 0x4005.

Here is my code for your reference:

```py
import os
import urllib.parse
import PyPDF2 as pf
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime
from module.executables.query import EasyQuery
from module.warp_object import WarpObject
from bin.scripts.fetch_pdf import TableauPDFFetcher
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

# Fetch PDF and PNG
today_date = date.today()

pdf_flash = r'\\C:\SamplePDF_{}.pdf'.format(today_date)

pdf_object = open(pdf_flash,"rb") #rb stands for read binary
output = PdfFileWriter()
input = PdfFileReader(pdf_object)

input_numpages = input.getNumPages()

for i in range(input_numpages):
    output.addPage(input.getPage(i)) #insert page in the output file

parent_1 = output.addBookmark('Page 1', 2) # add parent bookmark

parent_2 = output.addBookmark('Page 2', 3) 
output.addBookmark('Traffic', 3, parent_2)
output.addBookmark('Gross Revenue (Stable)', 5, parent_2)
output.addBookmark('Conversion Rate', 7, parent_2)
output.addBookmark('Average Order Value', 9, parent_2)
output.addBookmark('Gross Revenue Per Visit', 11, parent_2)

pdf_flash1 = r'\\C:\SamplePDF_{}.pdf'.format(today_date)

result_pdf = open(pdf_flash, "wb")
output.write(pdf_flash1)       

output.close()
```

It is throwing the error at the second last line `output.write(pdf_flash1)`.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679706/how-to-edit-a-pdf-file-replacing-its-data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to edit a pdf file, replacing its data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679706/how-to-edit-a-pdf-file-replacing-its-data)

Comment: I have already looked at the above solutions mentioned by @isopach . However, I was wondering if there is an easier solution out there. For instance, changing the write mode or writing to a new file.

Comment: Did you get the solution for this? I am also facing the same error, I checked the answers mentioned in the comments, but I am not writing to the same file.

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me.

Instead of

```
pdf_flash = r'\\C:\SamplePDF_{}.pdf'.format(today_date)
pdf_object = open(pdf_flash,"rb") #rb stands for read binary
input = PdfFileReader(pdf_object)
```

use:

```
pdf_path = 'sample_PDF.pdf'
input = PdfFileReader(pdf_path, strict = False)
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.